# Can I write something like this: "I found an answer on is and why is it important to do that."

Tags: sentence-construction, punctuation

In Serbian, there is a nice way to say this and would love to find a way to do the same in English.

Basically, I would like to make two statements in one sentence, second (*why*) related to answer on the first (*is*). Still, I don't want to suggest that subject *is* but to show knowledge of high possibility that it exists.

On the bonus side, is my title grammatically correct? Does question mark comes after dot and double-quote? What is the right order?

> Can I write something like this: "I found an answer on is and why is
>   it important to do that."?

Comment: It's taken me some time to understand your question! I believe the 'is' between 'on' & 'and' is intentional, e.g. it's not an 'it'. It expresses existence. Secondly, I think the end is incorrect, it should be 'why it is important to do that' (question in _indirect/reported speech_).

Comment: I don't understand the question or the explanation of the question.  What is **is**?  Do you mean **whether and why**?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your statement, but you might be looking for "I found an answer on **why it is**".  In English "an answer on" has to be followed by a noun, not a verb.

Answer (score 1):

Punctuation is key!  It is the difference between "Let's eat, grandma!" and "Let's eat grandma!"  Please use punctuation!  You may be saving lives!

Using the proper punctuation here I think makes the meaning clear:

> I found an answer on is, and *why* is it important to do that.

Though better written, you would probably write:

> I found an answer on if, and why it is important to do that.